# ServiceStack 4 C# client async call hangs

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am using ServiceStack 4 client to access a RESTful api endpoint. I have written two methods to return a list of objects. The synchronize method returns data as expected. The async methods hangs on the line :

```
var response = await client.GetAsync<List<Debtor>>("api/Debtor");
```

This is how my methods are defined:

```
    public async Task<List<Debtor>> GetDebtorsAsync()
    {
        var debtors = new List<Debtor>();

        try
        {
            var client = new JsonServiceClient(GlobalSingleton.ServerURI);
            var response = await client.GetAsync<List<Debtor>>("api/Debtor");
            debtors = response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return debtors;
    }

    List<Debtor> IDebtorDal.GetDebtors()
    {
        var debtors = new List<Debtor>();

        try
        {
            var client = new JsonServiceClient(GlobalSingleton.ServerURI);
            var response = client.Get<List<Debtor>>("api/Debtor");
            var r = response.GetResponseStatus();
            debtors = response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var x = ex.Message;
            throw;
        }
        return debtors;
    }
```

Comment: We are experiencing the same behaviour. The frontend site (hosted on IIS) is calling the backend using the ServiceStack client, and we are seeing hanging calls (very frequently, although not always).

Answer (score 4):

The [ServiceStack Service Clients](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client) should only be used for calling [ServiceStack Services](https://servicestack.net/). You can use [HTTP Utils](http://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils) for calling 3rd party (i.e. non-ServiceStack) services.

The `JsonServiceClient` uses .NET's `HttpWebRequest` which has a default limit on the number of concurrent HTTP Requests to a single domain which you can increase with:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = n;
```

Alternatively for async requests you can use `JsonHttpClient` instead which is built on Microsoft's newer `HttpClient` which doesn't have these limits.

Comment: Setting the DefaultConnectionLimit did it for me! It seems to me it's a pretty important note to have in the docs: if an async interface is exposed, I would expect to be able to make multiple requests at a time. Instead, the application blocks, and the calls get stuck. May I suggest to update the documentation and do some testing regarding this behaviour?

Comment: @A.Chiesa Please read my answer again, the limit is per domain and this is the default behaviour of all .NET HttpWebRequest's. It's a .NET limit on concurrent requests per domain, it doesn't have anything to do with being an Async interface.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But the SS Client is deadlocking an application if called more than once at a time (pretty common when used on a web site), by default. Now I know this is not related to SS implementation, but don't you think it should be documented somewhere on SS docs? It seems to me pretty important, as a word of caution. Thanks for the answer, for your time, and for this impressive library.

Comment: Btw, deadlocking instead of queuing the requests seem to me a bug. I don't know if in ServiceStack or in .Net, but something somewhere is broken.

Comment: @A.Chiesa The default limit blocks all other requests to the domain, that's just how it works otherwise it wouldn't be a limit. Again this is .NETs default behaviour, there is no locking in the Service Client, it just creates a new HttpWebRequest per request, whether or not the Request is allowed to go through depends on whether you've exceeded the limits or not. It's not a bug, it's intended behaviour, if you want greater limits use the ServicePointManager to increase them or if you want a client without these limits use the JsonHttpClient like I've specified in my answer.

Comment: You're not getting the problem. The requests are not blocked temporarily: they are deadlocked as soon as you go over the limit (which is quite easy, by default). You don't get an exception, nor a response, and the process stays unresponsively undead forever. This cannot be "intended behaviour".

Comment: @A.Chiesa it is the behaviour to never exceed the limits, the async requests stay inflight and never complete, using sync requests should avoid the hanging in-flight requests otherwise  increase the limits or use a different client.

Comment: In other words: don't use the async capabilities of the C# client for parallel execution, because it is broken by default and by design. I don't see how in the world one can use the async methods without problems. To add to this, there is nothing at all in the docs (a simple warning would be enough). Thanks for your help: it solved our problem, but asserting there is no problem, is just plain wrong. "In-flight requests", as you call them, should never happen, so, there is a bug.

Comment: Again you're hitting .NETs default limits, increase the limits or use a different client. It is the MSDN docs because that's where the limit is imposed.